# Error al compilar una vista en asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp

Hola estoy trabajando con un proyecto atravez de github cuando creo el controlador y le asigno una vista a una de las acciones me da el error:

HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

se que el proceso de crear el controlador y la vista estan bien  porque si lo hago en un proyecto aparte todos los pasos si compila la vista pero en este de github en el cual estoy trabajando no lo hace sera algo del proyecto? adjunto el codigo.

Controlador

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Proy.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Login
        public ActionResult log()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

y la vista asi

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "log";
}

<h2>log</h2>
```

de momento solo he creado el controlador y una vista para la prueba porque solo me da este error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El proyecto ya tiene otros controladores y vistas funcionando pero las que yo creo son las que dan este error y si trato de crear una acción y vista en un controlador existente me da el mismo error.

Comment: puedes agregar como esta estructurado el proyecto, las rutas de las vistas y los controladores

Comment: ¿Será que no está compilando o te está dando un error? Y por tanto los cambios que haces no se aplican ya que solo ves la versión anterior. No es que me haya pasado a mi ....